# Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, gradle, dropwizard

I am trying to create Gradle/DropWizard (JDK 1.8) application using IntelliJ
When attempting to run I receive:
**Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.**

Below is a complete code:

```
package org.xx.udemy;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

public class DropWizApp extends Application<Configuration> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello DropWiz!");
    }
    public static void main(String ...args) throws Exception{
        new DropWizApp().run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above with Dropwizard 1.3.16: Emtpy initialize(...) and run(...) methods. It starts the server and in the console there is a log that no resources are registered. So you could check the version of Dropwizard you are using and try some older one.

Comment: You haven't registered any resources. With older versions of Dropwizard that still use Jersey 1.x, you will get this message. You should use the newest version of Dropwizard if you are just getting started.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading dropwizard's version solved the problem.